# LEFT JOIN issue in table to get the desire output

Tags: sql-server, left-join

**Table A**

```
---------------------
ProjectID   Column1
---------------------
1           Test1
1           Test2
1           Test3
---------------------
```

**Table B**

```
---------------------
ProjectID   Column1
---------------------
1           Test1
1           Test2
```

I want to get the below result if the value is available in table B then return *"Selected"*, otherwise - *"Unselected"*.

```
-----------------------
Column1     Output
-----------------------
Test1        Selected
Test2        Selected
Test3        Unselected
```

I tried the below query to get output:

```
Select A.Column1, 
       CASE When A.Column1=B.Column1 Then 'Selected' ELSE 'Unselected' as Output 
       from Table A LEFT JOIN Table B on A.PrjectID=B.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.Column1, 
       case when max(B.Column1) is null 
            then 'unselected' 
            else 'selected' 
       end as Output 
from Table A 
LEFT JOIN Table B on A.Column1 = B.Column1
group by A.Column1
```

Comment: `A.PrjectID = B.ProjectID` is not needed, at least for the result he wants. With that you will get also Test2 Unselected

Comment: When i used above query it is giving me duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Hi I modified your code , Please try this for your solution:

```
Select A.Column1, 
       CASE When A.Column1=B.Column1 Then 'Selected' ELSE 'UnSelected' 
       END as Output_ 
from Table A 
LEFT JOIN Table B on A.PrjectID=B.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work (even if there are more than 1 ProjectIDs in tables A and B).

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTESTa;
go
select * INTO #tTESTa from (values 
(1, 'test1'),
(1, 'test2'),
(1, 'test3')) V(ProjectID, Column1);

drop table if exists #tTESTb;
go
select * INTO #tTESTb from (values 
(1, 'test1'),
(1, 'test2')) V(ProjectID, Column1);
```

Query

```
select ta.Column1, 
       case when tb.ProjectID is null then 'Unselected' else 'Selected' end OutPut
from #tTESTa ta
     left join #tTESTb tb on ta.ProjectID=tb.ProjectID
                             and ta.Column1=tb.Column1;
```

Output

```
Column1 OutPut
test1   Selected
test2   Selected
test3   Unselected
```